# Problema con las funciones asíncronas de node, trato de ejecutar de manera síncrona

Tags: nodejs

Tengo este gran problema, quiero mostrar el html con los resultados de la consulta pero primero brinca la consulta, imprime el html y después me manda los resultados a causa de la asincronicidad de node, por consecuencia nunca los muestra por que se tarda en la consulta y el código sigue avanzando.
si alguien me pudiera ayudar a resolver esta parte, como evito que se siga ejecutando el código hasta que acabe la consulta.
ya intenté las funciones async - await pero aun asi brinca hasta el return html y no me regresa nada.

```
function tablas(idCliente) {
    const db = "mongodb://localhost/x";
    mongoose.connection.openUri(db, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log('Conectado a MongoDB');
        }
    });

    mongo.connect(db, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);

        cons = {
            'status': 'pendiente'
        }

        db.collection('ser').find(cons, function(err, res) {

            res.toArray(function(err, res) {

                arregloResultados = res;

                db.close();

            });
        });
    });

    var arr;

    var html = [];

    c = 0;

    myFuncion(arregloResultados);

    function myFuncion(arregloResultados) {
        try {

            arregloResultados.forEach(function(value) {

                if (idCliente == value.idCliente) {

                    html[c] = '<tbody>';
                    html[c] += '<tr>';
                    html[c] += '<td data-column="Foto"><img width="300em" height="150em" src="/imagenes/' + value.idFotografo + '.jpg" class="thumbnail"/></td>';
                    html[c] += '<td data-column="Direccion">' + value.direccion + '</td>';
                    html[c] += '<td data-column="Fecha">' + value.fecha + '</td>';
                    html[c] += '<td data-column="Hora">' + value.hora + '</td>';
                    html[c] += '<td data-column="Cantidad">' + value.cantidad + '</td>';
                    html[c] += '<td data-column="Horas">' + value.horas + '</td>';
                    html[c] += '<form class="" method="post" action="/AceptarCliente">'
                    html[c] += '<td data-column="Acción"><button type="submit" class="button-xsmall pure-button">Aceptar</button>'
                    html[c] += '<form class="" method="post" action="/RechazarCliente">'
                    html[c] += '<td data-column="Rechazar"><button type="submit" class="pure-button button-xsmall">Rechazar</button>'
                    html[c] += '</form></td>'
                    //html[c] += '<td data-column="Acción"><a href="https://www.google.com"class="icono-check"></a><a //href="https://www.google.com"class="icono-cross"></a></td>';
                    html[c] += '</tr>';
                    html[c] += '</tbody>';

                    //}

                    c++;
                }


            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("falta el arreglo");
        }
    }

    return html;
}
```

Comment: Hola Osiris Espinoza. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. **No uses** mayusculas porque en internet significa estar gritando. Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta y usa `ctr+k` para formatear tu codigo correctamente. Un saludo

Comment: Esto es algo aparte de tu pregunta y por eso lo coloco como comentario. Es muy mala práctica mezclar javascript y html de ese modo porque complica la lectura y el mantenimiento del código. Es el temible código espagueti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema con tu codigo es que tienes que manejar la respuesta de tu consulta dentro del callback. Esa es la forma de manejar las funciones asyncronas en nodejs.

En tu caso es ejecutar la llamada a `myFuncion(arregloResultados)`

```
var cons = {
    status: 'pendiente',
};

db.collection('ser').find(cons, (err, res) => {
    res.toArray((err, res) => {
        arregloResultados = res;

        myFuncion(arregloResultados);

        db.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: Efectivamente continnua con la función pero en lo que está "construyendo" el html brinca hasta el return y me lo regresa vacio